# i was born in estonia in 1981, can i claim the Estoniain citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, estonia

i was born in estonia, in 1981, at that time there was no estonian passport, my mother(born in estonia) and grandmother holding estonian passport, they got their passports in 1992, directly after the independance, but for some reason, my mother did not transmit the citizenchip to me, (i had the total right at that time, cause i was under 18) is there any chance to claim it now?